# alpha beta prunning in game tree with chance node

Tags: artificial-intelligence, alpha-beta-pruning

I am trying to learn alpha beta prunning in game tree with chance node so I found an example and worked on that after solving my tree it looks like this:

[image]

Now I have couple of **questions :**

- First, if we imagine that the range for leaves are from -infinity and +infinity can I say that only node that is pruned is the rightmost one?
- another question is that, if we imagine that the range for leaves are from -2 to 2,can I say that only circled area from the following picture would be pruned(Or maybe I am wrong and it should not be pruned)?

[image]

Comment: I believe this is called an Expectimax search, not alpha-beta, since it uses the chance nodes.